# Repeater row expand upon click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, panel, repeater

I want my repeater row - when clicked expand with few textboxes in a panel.Here i have done the repeater in a table format with the datas from database.when each row in the repeater is clicked i need a panel to be visible with textbox in it.when the row is clicked again then the panel must become invisible.

Thanks in advance for the help

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepSample" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="font-family: Verdana;
            border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; background-color: #D8D8D8">
            <tr bgcolor="#FF781E">
                <th>
                    LicenseID
                </th>
                <th>
                    LicenseName
                </th>
                <th>
                    StartDate
                </th>
                <th>
                    EndDate
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: White">
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LicenseID")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LicenseName")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.StartDate")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EndDate")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LicenseID")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LicenseName")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.StartDate")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EndDate")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KTestConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT LicenseID, LicenseName, StartDate, EndDate FROM Krish">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: you need to re write your question, what are you trying to do.. what have you tried so far.. if you get errors what are they

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can help...

Make your **jQuery plugin** with the below jQuery code...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
            //Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
            return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    //Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='collapsibleContainerContent'></div>");

    //Create a new div as the first item within the container.
    $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle'></div>").prependTo($(this));

    //Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);
}

function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    //The item clicked is the new div... get this parent (the overall container) and toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}
```

**aspx markup part**

Put a div inside your `Repeater` `ItemTemplate` and give it the class *collapsibleContainer*

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="collapsibleContainer">
            <%-- Put your text boxes and other contents here --%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, only thing left is **$().ready** function in your page.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".collapsibleContainer").collapsiblePanel();
});
```

Of course you will need to include the jQuery plugin reference as a script tag on your page.